# show sets are or aren't bounded in an linear ordered set

Tags: analysis, order-theory

> Let $X$ be a linearly ordered set, and $A\subset Y\subset X$.
>
> - Can it happen that $A$ is bounded in $X$, but not in $Y$?
> - Can it happen that $A$ is bounded in $Y$, but not in $X$?

I'm thinking that they both cannot happen but I'm not sure of an explanation

Comment: The first question cannot be true. If $A$ is bounded in $X$, then $A$ must be bounded in $Y$, since $Y \subset X$.

Comment: Instead of posting an image, you should type in the question.  This makes the post load faster, helps internet searches, and helps teachers detect instances of cheating.

Comment: For $X=\mathbb{N}$, $Y=[0,\infty)$, $X=[0,\infty]$, we have that $X$ is bounded in $X$ but is not bounded in $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

- We can take $A:=\mathbb{N}$, $Y:=[0,\infty)$ and $X:=[0,\infty]$, where $\forall x\in Y, x<\infty$. Then $A$ is bounded in $X$ (by $\infty$) while $X$ is not bounded in $Y$.
- If $y_0\in Y$ is a bound for $A$ in $Y$. Then $y_0\in X$. Therefore $A$ is bounded by $y_0$ in $X$.